# SharePoint: Script to automatically import documents from a network share on a regular schedule

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, windows-services

I am new to SharePoint development.

I am trying automate the task of:

- Uploading documents from a network share to a SharePoint document library.
- The related metadata for each of the files also need to be brought into the SharePoint columns. (will taken from a single CSV file in the same location with filenames mapped in it)
- This process needs to automatically run on a predefined schedule (eg: daily/once an hour etc)

I want to know:

- What is the best way to achieve this? (PowerShell script running on Windows task scheduler, creating a service etc.)
- Starting point for coding or any code already available since it looks like this might be a very common requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically StackOverflow is the wrong place to ask this kind of question. But, since I just finished creating a script for uploading files to SharePoint from a CSV, I thought I can share it.

**Disclaimer:** *I offer no guarantees that this will work with your environment, or that it will not mess things up. Review. Understand it. Use at own risk.*

The script can be easily changed to add/change columns, (under the `#Add Column Information` section)

CSV File format:

```
SubFolder,Name,Column1,Column2
```

Where SubFolder can be blank if your source file is on the root of the Source Folder. Name is the file name, and Column1 and Column2 are SharePoint columns.

Save the below code to the two PowerShell files. `ImportSPfromCSV.ps1` contains the logic, `Run_ImportSPfromCSV.ps1` contains the code to run it.

To run, set up a scheduled task on a SharePoint server (or server that has the SharePoint PowerShell module on it) and run with the command:

```
powershell.exe -file "C:\scripts\Run_ImportSPfromCSV.ps1"
```

**Run_ImportSPfromCSV.ps1**

```
    # Load  Script
    . .\ImportSPfromCSV.ps1 

    # Run Function
    Import-SPData -CSVFilePath "CSVFile.csv" -SourceFolder "C:\temp" -SiteURL "http://SharePointWebApp/sites/SiteCollection" -Library "Shared Documents" -Approve $true -CheckIn $true -Overwrite $false -OverwriteFields $true
```

**ImportSPfromCSV.ps1**

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Imports items into SharePoint library from a CSV File
.DESCRIPTION
    Imports items that are saved to disk into SharePoint library 
    using and tagging the information from a CSV File
.NOTES
    NAME:           ImportSPfromCSV.ps1
    AUTHOR:         Kristoph Minchau
    CREATED:        May 2, 2013
    LASTEDIT:   2014-03-06
    VERSION:        1.10
    KEYWORDS:       SharePoint

    REVISION LOG:
    [2013/05/01] - km - v1.00 ** Created **
    [2014-03-06] - km - v1.10 * Minor edits

.EXAMPLE
    # Load  Script
    . .\ImportSPfromCSV.ps1 

    # Run Function
    Import-SPData -CSVFilePath "CSVFile.csv" -SourceFolder "C:\temp" -SiteURL "http://SharePointWebApp/sites/SiteCollection" -Library "Shared Documents" -Approve $true -CheckIn $true -Overwrite $false -OverwriteFields $true
.LINK
    Import-SPData
#>


Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue



<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Get SharePoint file
.DESCRIPTION
    Gets a SharePoint File
.PARAMETER SPFileName
    The file name to Upload to the SharePoint library if different than original File name
    ex. "NewName.docx"
    [String]
.PARAMETER Web
    The SharePoint web site
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]
.PARAMETER Library
    The Destination Library on SharePoint
    Default value = "Retail Banking"
.INPUTS
    System.String SPFileName
.OUTPUTS
    System.String Return SPFile
.EXAMPLE
    $Web = Get-SPWeb "http://SharePointWebApp/sites/SiteCollection"
    Get-SPFile -Web $Web -Library "Shared Documents" -SPFileName "File1.doc"
.LINK
    Get-SPFile
#>
Function Get-SPFile {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
            [string]$SPFileName,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$Web,
        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$Library = "Shared Documents"
    ) #end param
    Process
    {
        Try
        {
            # Get Library
            $docLibrary = $web.Lists[$Library]
            $folder = $docLibrary.RootFolder

            # Assign the new document name, and build the destination SharePoint path
            $SPFilePath = ($folder.URL + "/" + $SPFileName)

            #Check if the file exists and the overwrite option is selected before adding the file
            $spFile = $web.GetFile($SPFilePath)

            #Return SP File
            Write-Output $spFile

        } #end Try
        Catch
        {
            Write-Error $Error[0]
        }
    } #end Process
} #end Get-SPFile



<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Adds a file to SharePoint Document Library.
.DESCRIPTION
    Adds a file to SharePoint Document Library, optionally checks it in, approve it, or overwrite it.
.PARAMETER FilePath
    The file to Upload
    ex. "c:\Test.docx"
    [String]
.PARAMETER SPFileName
    The file name to Upload to the SharePoint library. 
    Rename the File to something that is SharePoint/URL friendly (e.g. remove special characters "/?=<>" etc.)
    ex. "NewName.docx"
    [String]
.PARAMETER Web
    The SharePoint web site
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]
.PARAMETER Library
    The Destination Library on SharePoint
    [String]
.PARAMETER Approve
    If approval workflow is enabled, when uploading the document, approve the uploaded document
    [bool] Default value = $true
.PARAMETER CheckIn
    If workflow is enabled, when uploading the document, CheckIn the uploaded document
    [bool] Default value = $true
.PARAMETER Overwrite
    When uploading the document, if a document with the same name is encountered, overwrite the document?
    [bool] Default value = $false
.INPUTS
    N/A - Pipeline Inputs
.OUTPUTS
    SP File
.EXAMPLE
    $Web = Get-SPWeb "http://SharePointWebApp/sites/SiteCollection"
    Add-SPFileToLibrary -File "Test.docx" -SPFileName "NewName.docx" -Web $Web -Library "Shared Documents" -Approve $true -CheckIn $true -Overwrite $false
.LINK
    Add-SPFileToLibrary
#>
Function Add-SPFileToLibrary {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
            [string]$FilePath,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$SPFileName,
        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)]
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$Web,
        [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$Library,
        [Parameter(Position=4, Mandatory=$true)]
            [bool]$Approve = $true,
        [Parameter(Position=5, Mandatory=$true)]
            [bool]$CheckIn = $true,
        [Parameter(Position=6, Mandatory=$true)]
            [bool]$Overwrite = $false
    ) #end param
    Process
    {
        Try
        {
            # Get Library
            $docLibrary = $web.Lists[$Library]
            $folder = $docLibrary.RootFolder

            # Assign the new document name, and build the destination SharePoint path
            $SPFilePath = ($folder.URL + "/" + $SPFileName)

            #Check if the file exists and the overwrite option is selected before adding the file
            if ((!$web.GetFile($SPFilePath).Exists) -or ($Overwrite))
            {
                $Message = "Uploading...   $FilePath   ...To...   $SPFilePath"
                Write-Debug $Message
                Write-Verbose $Message

                #Support for -WhatIf parameter
                if($PsCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Message))
                {
                    Write-Host $Message

                    #Upload file
                    $File = Get-ChildItem $FilePath
                    $spFile = $folder.Files.Add($SPFilePath, $File.OpenRead(), $true)  #Upload with overwrite = $true (SP file path, File stream, Overwrite?)

                    $spItem = $spFile.Item

                    #Check in file to document library (if required)
                    #MinorCheckIn=0, MajorCheckIn=1, OverwriteCheckIn=2
                    If ($CheckIn) {
                        If ($spFile.CheckOutStatus -ne "None") {
                            If ($Overwrite){
                                #$spFile.CheckIn("File copied from " + $filePath, 2)
                                $spFile.CheckIn("Version 1.0", 2)
                            }
                            Else
                            {
                                #$spFile.CheckIn("File copied from " + $filePath, 1)
                                $spFile.CheckIn("Version 1.0", 1)
                            }
                            Write-Host "$spfile.Name Checked In"
                        }
                    } #end CheckIn

                    #Approve file (if required)
                    If ($Approve)
                    {
                        If ($spItem.ListItems.List.EnableModeration -eq $true)
                        {
                            #$spFile.Approve("File automatically approved after copying from " + $filePath)
                            $spFile.Approve("Approved")
                            If ($spFile.Item["Approval Status"] -eq 0)
                            {
                                Write-Host "$spfile.Name Approved"
                            }
                            Else
                            {
                                Write-Host -Background Yellow -Foreground Black "Warning: $spfile.Name Not Approved"
                            }
                        }
                    } #end Approve

                    #Return SP File
                    Write-Output $spFile

                }# end upload file
            }
            Else
            {
                If($web.GetFile($SPFilePath).Exists)
                {
                    Write-Verbose "File Exists and Overwrite = $false returning file"
                    # File Exists and Overwrite = $false, Try finding and returning the file
                    $spFile = Get-SPFile -Web $web -Library $Library -SPFileName $SPFileName

                    #Return SP File
                    Write-Output $spFile
                }
                else
                {
                    # File does not exist, and Overwrite = $false, we can't return anything, Throw Warning
                    Write-Host -Background Yellow -Foreground Black "Warning: $SPFilePath does not Exist and Overwrite is set to False. No SP File handle returned"
                    Write-Output $null
                }
            }# end File Exists and Overwrite Check

        } #end Try
        Catch
        {
            Write-Error $Error[0]
        }
    } #end Process
} #end Add-SPFileToLibrary





<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Imports files into SharePoint library from a CSV File
.DESCRIPTION
    Imports files that are saved to disk into SharePoint library 
    using and tagging the information from a CSV File
.PARAMETER CSVFilePath
    The CSV import file to use to import the data from
    Default value = "CSVFile.csv"
.PARAMETER SourceFolder
    The Source Folder for locating the Public Folder files
    Default value = "."
.PARAMETER SiteURL
    The Site URL on SharePoint
    Default value = "http://SharePointWebApp/sites/SiteCollection"
.PARAMETER Library
    The Destination Library on SharePoint
    Default value = "Shared Documents"
.PARAMETER Approve
    If approval workflow is enabled, when uploading the document, approve the uploaded document
    [bool] Default value = $true
.PARAMETER CheckIn
    If workflow is enabled, when uploading the document, CheckIn the uploaded document
    [bool] Default value = $true
.PARAMETER Overwrite
    When uploading the document, if a document with the same name is encountered, overwrite the document?
    [bool] Default value = $false
.PARAMETER OverwriteFields
    If the document is already uploaded, overwrite the fields with the fields from the CSV file
    [bool] Default value = $true
.INPUTS
    N/A - Pipeline Inputs
.OUTPUTS
    System.String Returns
.EXAMPLE
    #Default Initial Import of all data
    Import-SPData -CSVFilePath "CSVFile.csv" -SourceFolder "C:\temp" -SiteURL "http://SharePointWebApp/sites/SiteCollection" -Library "Shared Documents" -Approve $true -CheckIn $true -Overwrite $false -OverwriteFields $true
.LINK
    Import-SPData
#>
Function Import-SPData {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
            [string]$CSVFilePath = "CSVFile.csv",
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$SourceFolder = ".",
        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$SiteURL = "http://SharePointWebApp/sites/SiteCollection",
        [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$Library = "Shared Documents",
        [Parameter(Position=4, Mandatory=$true)]
            [bool]$Approve = $true,
        [Parameter(Position=5, Mandatory=$true)]
            [bool]$CheckIn = $true,
        [Parameter(Position=6, Mandatory=$true)]
            [bool]$Overwrite = $false,
        [Parameter(Position=7, Mandatory=$true)]
            [bool]$OverwriteFields = $true
    ) #end param
    Process
    {
        Try
        {
            #Get Web
            $web = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl

            Write-Host -Background Black -Foreground Green "Uploading Documents..."

            # Loop through the CSV file entries
            Import-Csv $CSVFilePath | ForEach-Object{

                # File Path
                if($_.Subfolder)
                {
                    #Subfolder exists
                    $FilePath = ($SourceFolder + "\" + $_.Subfolder + "\" + $_.Name)
                }
                else
                {
                    #Subfolder does not exist
                    $FilePath = ($SourceFolder + "\" + $_.Name)
                }

                # Assign the new document name, and build the destination SharePoint path
                $SPFileName = $_.Name

                # Add the file to the SP Library. Don't approve or check in yet because we have to change the column values.
                $spFile = Add-SPFileToLibrary -FilePath $FilePath -SPFileName $SPFileName -Web $web -Library $Library -Approve $Approve -CheckIn $CheckIn -Overwrite $Overwrite

                if($spFile -And $OverwriteFields)
                {
                    $spItem = $spFile.Item

                    $Message = "Changing column values for $($_.Name) ..."
                    Write-Debug $Message
                    Write-Verbose $Message

                    #Support for -WhatIf parameter
                    if($PsCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Message))
                    {
                        Write-Host $Message

                        #Add Column Information
                        Try
                        {
                            # Column1
                            Write-Verbose "Setting Column1 to $($_.Column1)"
                            $spItem["Column1"] = $($_.Column1)

                            # Column2
                            Write-Verbose "Setting Column1 to $($_.Column2)"
                            $spItem["Column2"] = $($_.Column2)

                            #Update document with new column values
                            $spItem.SystemUpdate($false)

                            Write-Host "...Complete"
                        }
                        Catch
                        {
                            Write-Error "Error Changing Column information"
                            Write-Error $Error[0]
                        }
                    }#end Change Column values
                }
                else
                {
                    if($OverwriteFields)
                    {
                        # No file handle returned
                        Write-Host -Background DarkRed -ForeGround Yellow "Error: File not uploaded or no File handle returned: $_.Name"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        # File handle returned, but OverwriteFields = $false
                        Write-Verbose "Not modifying any columns for $_.Name"
                    }
                }#end if $spFile is set to something and OverwriteFields = $true
            } #end CSV loop
        } #end Try
        Catch
        {
            Write-Error $Error[0]
        }
    } #end Process
} #end function Import-SPData
```

Comment: Awesome detailed answer! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Could you let me know how I could change the user that the script uploads the document as? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately using SharePoint PowerShell cmdlets, you can't specify a user to use in the script. It assumes that whoever is running the PowerShell prompt has the appropriate rights to upload documents.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've seen on SO. The details are excellent, and special props for using all the PowerShell function parameters well. I've definitely learned a bit from this. We did use an XML file for all the input parameters, but otherwise this script worked perfectly for us.